# Variance Inflation Factors for a glm with clustered standard errors

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity, clustered-standard-errors, variance-inflation-factor

I am using the glm.cluster function in R package miceadds and I would like to calculate the variance inflation factors (VIF), much as the vif function in R package car does. If I try to use car::vif I get the error:

```r
> car::vif(FitglmC)
Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute
```

If I estimate without the clustered standard errors I get useful output:

```r
> car::vif(Fitglm)
                 GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
Var1         1.557939  5        1.045334
Var2         1.417087  8        1.022027
Var3         2.566609  1        1.602064
Var4         2.706188  1        1.645049
Var5         4.366706  6        1.130697
Var6        15.355811  7        1.215441
Var7         1.201265  3        1.031034
```

You will note that I have some factor variables (Df>1) in the model.

Looking to understand how car::vif calculates VIF, I see that it mainly uses the variance-covariance matrix (v) to perform the calculation (ignoring the intercept term), with this being the core piece of code.

```r
  R <- cov2cor(v)
  detR <- det(R)
  result <- matrix(0, n.terms, 3)
  rownames(result) <- terms
  colnames(result) <- c("GVIF", "Df", "GVIF^(1/(2*Df))")
  for (term in 1:n.terms) {
    subs <- which(assign == term)
    result[term, 1] <- det(as.matrix(R[subs, subs])) * 
        det(as.matrix(R[-subs, -subs]))/detR
    result[term, 2] <- length(subs)
  }
```

The VIF value for a term in the regression in essence being :

```r
the determinant of the subset of the correlation matrix just for the term under scrutiny *
the determinant of the subset of the correlation matrix without the term under scrutiny /
the determinant of the correlation matrix
```

Is this a valid way for me to calculate the VIF for a clustered glm?

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted the code piece above and, using the variance-covariance matrix from the glm.clustered model result, I have calculated the GVIF's for a clustered glm.

The main struggle was getting hold of the terms in the model data frame. After that the calculations were easy.

```r
Gvif <- function(FitglmC){
# Terms in the model
  str<-as.character(FitglmC$glm_res$formula)
  str<-gsub("\n","",str,fixed=TRUE)
  str<-gsub(" ","",str,fixed=TRUE)
  Fit.terms<-strsplit(str, "\\+")[[3]]
  Fit.names<-names(FitglmC$glm_res$coefficients)
  x<-cov2cor(vcov(FitglmC))
# Remove the intercept
  x<-x[-1,-1]
# Calculations
  R<-det(x)
  for (v in 1:length(Fit.terms)){
    sub<-grepl(Fit.terms[[v]],Fit.names[-1])
    nsub<-!sub
    Df<-sum(sub)
    if (Df>1){
      R11<-det(x[sub,sub])
      R22<-det(x[nsub,nsub])
      vif<-R11*R22/R
    } else {
      R11<-x[sub,sub]
      R22<-det(x[nsub,nsub])
      vif<-R11*R22/R
    }
    gvif<-vif^(1/(2*Df))
    print(sprintf("%30s %2d %8.4f %8.4f 
          %8.3f",Fit.terms[[v]],Df,vif,gvif,gvif^2))
  }
}
```